# How to convert AV_PIX_FMT_YUYV422 to AV_PIX_FMT_GRAY8

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg and I am able to capture a picture from a camera, but the image is mono but the camera image is coming out as YUYV422, I tried the sws_scale call in ffmpeg to convert it from YUYV422 to AV_PIX_FMT_GRAY8 but it just errors out.

Has anyone done this, do I have to do multiple conversions to get a gray scale image out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can just take Y plane.

Comment: is there a way to do that in ffmpeg?

Comment: It is probably stored in `AVFrame::data` so there is no need to convert anything.

Comment: But isnt there 2 Y components, do I need to average them?  Sorry I dont know too much about pixel formats

Comment: No,  subsampling is applied only to color components. There is 0.5 of U and V components per pixel. That is stored U and V components are average per two pixels while Y component is specified for each pixel. Y component is basically a grayscale picture and U and V are colors.

Comment: Thank you!  That worked, I just wrote a for loop and took every other pixel!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167481/discussion-between-godspped-and-vtt).